# Using values inside a cte in snowflake queries

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I'm trying to use values inside a cte in snowflake. For example, this:

```
WITH person (id, name)
     AS (VALUES (1, 'Ted'), (2, 'Bill'))
SELECT *
FROM   person;
```

works fine in (for example) postgres, but gives me the following error in snowflake:

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 9 unexpected 'VALUES'. syntax error line 2 at position 17 unexpected '1'. syntax error line 2 at position 26 unexpected ','.
```

However, from snowflake documentation I can see VALUES syntax is supported, for example this works in snowflake:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 'Ted'), (2, 'Bill')) as person (id, name);
```

So I'm wondering how I'd get it to work inside a cte.

I would like the same output as I would get from postgres (using a cte)

```
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | Ted
  2 | Bill
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a SELECT statement inside your CTE

```
WITH person AS (
    SELECT $1 AS id,
           $2 AS name
    FROM (VALUES (1, 'Ted'), (2, 'Bill'))
)
SELECT *
FROM   person;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can define table and column alias like this:

```
select * from (values (1, 'One'), (3, 'three')) as person (ID, NAME);
```

And then of course reference the table expression in a CTE:

```
WITH PERSON as
(
    select * from (values (1, 'One'), (3, 'three')) as person (ID, NAME)
)
SELECT * FROM person;
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close

```
with person (id, name) as 
(select * from values (1, 'ted'), (2, 'bill'))

select *
from person;
```